# Rails: Matching Comment id to Specific Micropost id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, post, associations

Currently I am have a comment which belongs to a micropost, but the issue is, when a user creates a comment, the comment gets stored in the database with a micropost id but the id is not for the specific micropost rather it seem as though the comment just incremented the micropost id by + 1. Very confused and would very much appreciate any help. Thank you!

**Comment Model**

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :user_id, :micropost_id
  belongs_to :micropost
  belongs_to :user

  validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 }


  default_scope order: 'comments.created_at DESC'
end
```

**Micropost Model**

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :content, :view_count
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments
end
```

**Comments Controller**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController 
  def create
    @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:micropost_id])
    @comment = @micropost.comments.build(params[:comment])
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id
    @comment.save 
      respond_to do |format|
      format.html 
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

**Form**

```
<div class="CommentField">
<%= form_for ([@micropost, @micropost.comments.new]) do |f| %>
<%= f.text_area :content, :class => "CommentText", :placeholder => "Write a Comment..." %>
<div class="CommentButtonContainer">
<%= f.submit "Comment", :class => "CommentButton b1" %>
</div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

**Routes**

```
  resources :microposts do
    resources :comments
  end
```

**Raked Routes**

```
micropost_comments     GET    /microposts/:micropost_id/comments(.:format)          comments#index
                       POST   /microposts/:micropost_id/comments(.:format)          comments#create
 new_micropost_comment GET    /microposts/:micropost_id/comments/new(.:format)      comments#new
edit_micropost_comment GET    /microposts/:micropost_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format) comments#edit
     micropost_comment GET    /microposts/:micropost_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#show
                       PUT    /microposts/:micropost_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                       DELETE /microposts/:micropost_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#destroy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue here is how much work you are putting into this. Rails is built to know about most of this without the need to do what you are doing. My suggestion would be to change your comments controller to something like this

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController 
  def create
    @comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])
    @comment.save 
      respond_to do |format|
      format.html 
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

since you are rendering your comments partial form through another partial you'll need to pass along the local variable of the associated post above it.

"comments/form", :locals => { :micropost => micropost } %>

and your form to something like this

```
<div class="CommentField">
<%= form_for ([micropost, @comment]) do |f| %>
<%= f.text_area :content, :class => "CommentText", :placeholder => "Write a Comment..." %>
<div class="CommentButtonContainer">
<%= f.submit "Comment", :class => "CommentButton b1" %>
</div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

In all my rails apps, that is all the association I would need to do for it to properly assign the Ids by itself. I'm sure that will fix the issue.

Comment: I have tried with just the `@comment = Comment.new` but the problem it runs across is that the micropost.id does not get put into the comment table :micropost_id integer

Comment: So the problem is actually with the association and not with the creation of the comments. Are you able to do `@micropost.comments` or `@comment.micropost` and receive any output from IRB?

Comment: With `@micropost.comments` I am able to get a comment to store in the db but the problem is that the comment wont store the right micropost id rather it just adds a micropost id of 1

Comment: I'm still unsure what the issue is here. If you are able to access the comments through the micropost then the Id is being set properly and the association is made. Do you need the micropost id cached on the comments entry for some reason that I'm not aware of or just for referencing?

Comment: As well as referencing but as well as the fact that micropost are all shown on the same page im not sure if the comments are posted in the right area, the comment is stored but the comment does not show up under the right area and I would like the comment to be post under the specific micropost through its id. I currently have a facebook like post and commenting system where each micropost has its own comment form and section.

Comment: you should be able to navigate to `localhost:3000/micropost(s)/id/comment(s)/id` or something to that effect. refer to your `rake routes` output for the exact url. That will tell you if the comments are being placed with the right micropost.

Comment: When I create comments through the form that i posted above, it comes out to be `localhost:3000/micropost(s)/1/comment(s)/id` everytime regardless which micropost the comment is posted under

I raked the routes and posted it above

Comment: Okay, then the issue is probably in how the @micropost variable is being defined on the controller action where the form is found. Can you post that code?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8276/discussion-between-justin-herrick-and-kellogs)